# Equivalent definitions of a contravariant functor

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let $\mathcal C,\mathcal D$ be categories. A *contravariant functor* from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$ is a functor $F$ from $\mathcal C^{op}$ to $\mathcal D$ . Another definition is given on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance

Why are they equivalent? Suppose the former definition holds. Every arrow in $\mathcal C^{op}$ is of the form $f^{op}:B\to A$ for some arrow  $f:A\to B$ is an arrow in $C$. We have $F(f^{op}): F(B)\to F(A)$, since $F$ is a functor. Also, if $g: B\to  C$, then $F(f^{op}\circ g^{op})=F(f^{op})\circ F(g^{op})$. 
How does it follow that $F(g\circ f)=F(f)\circ F(g)$? The converse isn't clear either...

Comment: $F(f^{op}): B\to A$? No, $F(f^{op}): F(B)\to F(A)$.

Comment: Right, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that $F(g\circ f)=F(f)\circ F(g)$ when viewing a contravariant functor as a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op}\to \mathcal{D}$ is that $f^{op}\circ_{\mathcal{C}^{op}} g^{op}=(g\circ_{\mathcal{C}} f)^{op}$ by the definition of composition in the opposite category. This is because, given two objects of $A,B\in \mathcal{C}$, $$\mathcal{C}^{op}(X,Y)=\mathcal{C}(Y,X)$$ and the composition operation on a pair of homsets $$\mathsf{comp}^{op}:\mathcal{C}^{op}(Y,Z)\times\mathcal{C}^{op}(X,Y)\to \mathcal{C}^{op}(X,Z)$$ is given by $$\mathsf{comp}^{op}=\mathsf{comp}\circ\tau:\mathcal{C}(Z,Y)\times\mathcal{C}(Y,X)\to\mathcal{C}(Z,X)$$ where $\mathsf{comp}$ is $\mathcal{C}$'s original composition operation, and $\tau$ is the twist function taking $(f,g)\mapsto(g,f)$. Again, this has nothing to do with the definition of a functor, this is just from the definition of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

So $F(g\circ_{\mathcal C} f)=F(f)\circ F(g)$ and $F(f^{op}\circ_{\mathcal{C}^{op}} g^{op})=F(f^{op})\circ F(g^{op})$ are actually the exact same equation, since $f^{op}=f$, and $g^{op}=g$.

Comment: That makes sense except that I still don't quite understand why $g^{op}=g$, considering that if $g$ is an arrow from $A$ to $B$, then $g^{op}$ is an arrow from $B$ to $A$. What is the definition of two arrows being equal?

Comment: $g^{op}$ is an object from $B\to A$ *in the opposite category of $\mathcal{C}$*. But an arrow from $B\to A$ in the opposite category is literally the same thing as an arrow from $A\to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Identity here is identity in the ambient set theory---as I mention in the first displayed equation, $\mathcal{C}^{op}(X,Y)$ and $\mathcal{C}(Y,X)$ are *the same set*, and have exactly the same members; when most category theorists write something like $g^{op}$, that "$op$" is just there as a reminder of which category we're thinking of the morphism as living in.

Comment: Personally, I think decorating the morphisms of the opposite category with $-^{op}$ is a bad idea, since it makes it look like we're applying some kind of operation to the morphism, when that's not really what's happening.