# The functors $\mathscr M^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ are the right $M$-sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-actions, monoid

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3293344/634426) shows that for a one-object category $\mathscr M$ with object $\star$ (corresponding to a monoid $M$), the functors $\mathscr M\to\mathbf{Set}$ are the left $M$-sets. I don't understand how to prove the similar statement about functors $\mathscr M^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ and *right* $M$-sets.

For example, let's try to assign to every such functor a right $M$-set.

Let $F: \mathscr M^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ be a functor. We need to find a set $S$ and a function $$S\times M\to M\\(s,m)\mapsto s\cdot m$$ sayisfying $s\cdot e=s$ and $s\cdot (m_1m_2)=(s\cdot m_1)\cdot m_2$.

There are no many choices for $S$. Let $S=F(\star)$. But I don't understand how $\mathscr M^{op}$ is different from $\mathscr M$ for a one-object category $\mathscr M$. Any arrow is equal to its opposite, and any two arrows can be composed in any order, right? In particular, this gives $$F(a)\circ F(b)=F(a\circ b)=F(b\circ a)=F(b)\circ F(a),$$ or am I wrong?

Anyway, how to define $\cdot$ using $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the answer by Guido A.; I'm posting it primarily for me.

Let $\star$ be the object of the one-object category $\mathscr M$.

Given a functor $F:\mathscr M^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$, set $S=F(\star)$ and define the right $M$-action on $S$

$$S\times M\to S,\\ (s,m)\mapsto s\cdot m$$ by $s\cdot m=F(m)(s)$.  Since $F(1_\star)=1_S$, we have $F(1_\star)(s)=1_S(s)$ or, equivalently, $s\cdot 1_\star=s$, which is the same as $s\cdot e=s$ where $e$ is the identity of $M$ (since the arrow $1_\star$ corresponds to $e$). Since, by definition, $m\circ_{op}m'=m'\circ m$, the functoriality condition $F(m\circ_{op}m')=F(m)\circ F(m')$ amounts to $F(m'\circ m)=F(m)\circ F(m')$, and evaluating at $s\in S$ gives $s\cdot (m'm)=(s\cdot m')\cdot m$, where we have used that $\circ$ corrresponds to monoid multiplication. In this way, a functor $\mathscr M^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$ gives rise to a right $M$-set.

Conversely, given a right $M$-set $(S,\cdot)$, define the functor (the fact that this is a functor is yet to be verified) $F:\mathscr M^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$ by $F(\star)=S$ and $F(m)(s)=s\cdot m$. The two conditions certifying that $\cdot$ is a right action then translate to the condition that $F$ is indeed a functor, just like above. In this way, a right $M$-set gives rise to a functor $\mathscr M^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$.

Answer (score 2):

> Any arrow is equal to its opposite, and any two arrows can be composed in any order, right?

Careful. These are arrows in different categories, so they cannot be equal. Also, you state that

> $F(a \circ b) = F(b \circ a)$

which is not in general true (I'm assuming that you think $a \circ b = b \circ a$ here).

For example, when in a one-object groupoid your statement is equivalent to saying that each pair of arrows $g,h : \ast \to \ast$ satisfy $gh = hg$. In other words, this would mean that for any group $G$ and $g,h \in G$ we have $gh = hg$. And it's a well known fact that this is not the case: these groups are called [abelian (or just commutative)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group).

The action is different because of how composition in the opposite category is defined. Take a look at left and right actions of groups: for example, a group $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication,

$$
g \cdot h := gh.
$$

It this also a right action? In general, no, as that would imply that for every $h,h',g \in G$ we have

$$
h'hg  = (h'h) \cdot g = h \cdot (h'g) = hh'g 
$$

which is not so (again if we take $g = 1$ this would imply that $G$ is abelian).

It's the same for functors $\mathscr{M}^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$. Having a left $M$-action on a set $S$ implies that for each $m,m' \in M$ and $s \in S$ we have

$$
(m'm)s = m'(ms)
$$

where as a right-action implies

$$
(m'm)s = m(m's).
$$

These notions are reflected in the way composition is defined in the opposite category. Given $m,m' : \ast \to \ast$, the composition $m \circ_{op} m'$ in $\mathscr{M}^{op}$ is defined to be the arrow $m' \circ  m$ in $\mathscr{M}$.

Hence a functor $F : \mathscr{M} \to \mathsf{Set}$ with $F(*) = S$ gives

$$
(m'm) \cdot s := F(m' \circ m)(s) = F(m') \circ F(m) (s) = F(m')(F(m)(s)) = m' \cdot (m \cdot s)
$$

and on the other hand a functor $F : \mathscr{M}^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ with $F(*) = S$ gives

$$
(m'm) \cdot s := F(m \circ_{op} m')(s) = F(m) \circ F(m') (s) = F(m)(F(m')(s)) = m \cdot (m' \cdot s).
$$

Note that the definition for $\mathscr{M}^{op}$ is exactly the same as the former, changing the category for its opposite. But as we refer always to arrows as they are in $\mathscr{M}$, everything gets reversed, which gives the 'first in last out' type of behaviour a right action has.

Comment: *These arrows are in different categories, so they cannot be equal.* [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3099489/634426) states that $f^{op}=f$, even though $f^{op}$ and $f$ live in different categories. Is the claim wrong? It's still hard for me to accept that claim, but it's easier for me to accept the analogous claim when the category has only one object. In such a case, all domains and codomains are the same. That's why I wrote that all arrows are equal to their opposites.

Comment: I mean, no, but one should be careful as to what that means. The arrow $f^{op}$ is defined to be $f$, but composition in the opposite category is not the same as in the original one. Hence one could say these are 'different'. 

Suppose that I consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{C}$. Is $1$ the same number in both constructions? Well, yes  (since the *set* itself is the same) but the vector spaces are not.

You can compose arrows which are in the same category. In particular, it is not so that $b \circ a = a \circ_{op} b$ is equal to $a \circ b$.

Comment: I'm not sure how weird this question will sound and whether the answer is something trivial, but is there a rigorous explanation of why $\circ$ is not the same as $\circ_{op}$ in this case?

Comment: I'm using $\circ_{op}$ to make explicit where we are composing these arrows. The composition of two arrows $a$ and $b$ of $\mathscr{M}^{op}$ is defined to be $b \circ a$ where as the composition in $\mathscr{M}$ is defined to be $a \circ b$. These would be equal if they are equal as arrows in $\mathscr{M}$, but there is no reason for them to be.

Comment: I think I got it: it's a more general statement. if $f:A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$ are arrows in a category, then their composition in the category is $g\circ f$ and their composition in the opposite category is $f^{op}\circ_{op} g^{op}=f\circ_{op} g$, and $g\circ f$ need not equal $f\circ_{op} g$. For other questions: you are saying that for a left $M$-action on $S$, one has $(m'm)s=m(m's)$. Why so? I would say one should have $(m'm)\cdot s=m'\cdot (m\cdot s)$ instead (where $\cdot$ is the action [it can be omitted if the action is multiplication]).

Comment: And similarly you are saying that for a right $M$-action on $S$, one has $(m'm)s=m'(ms)$. In my understanding, this is one of the axioms of the left $M$-action on $S$ by left multiplication. A right $M$-action $\cdot$, from my understanding, should satisfy $s\cdot (mm')=(s\cdot m)\cdot m'$. Am I confusing definitions? Also, I have no idea how you got $
h'hg  = (h'h) \cdot g = h \cdot (h'g) = hh'g 
$ and why this would be implied if the action by left multiplication were a right action.

Comment: My bad, you are right about the last part, I switched the commas. Fixing it asap.

Comment: Fixed. As for the other comment, it's as general as what I've said before: given arrows $f: A\to B, g:B \to C$ composable in $\mathcal{C}$, their composition $f \circ g$ in the opposite category is defined to be the arrow $gf$ of $\mathcal{C}$, viewed as an arrow of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$, and it need not be that $fg = gf$ (they may not be composable in both ways!).

Comment: Regarding the fixed portion about your left action: I think you should have some dots if you are talking about an abstract left action (which I guess you are since you write "**a** left $M$-action"). I still don't understand your axiom for a right action. According to Wikipedia, a right action satisfies $s\cdot (mm')=(s\cdot m)\cdot m'$. This is not what you have at all. Do I misunderstand the definition of a right action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96196/discussion-between-guido-a-and-user634426).